# find the rate where loadtype is "40-Year Fixed and subtype is "A"

Tags: xpath

I have the followng html structure
{code}

```
<rate>
    <loantype>40-Year Fixed Rate</loantype>
    <subtype>A</subtype>
    <rate> 5.500</rate>
    <points> 0.500</points>
    <apr> 5.579</apr>
    <jumbo>0</jumbo>
    <fixed>1</fixed>
  </rate>
```

{code}
...
and need to locate xPath for the rate where loantype is "40-Year Fixed Rate" and subtype is "A" using ancestor or child and parent. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: What is the expected output, do you need the rate text (5.500) or the rate node that contains that text (5.500) or do you need to select the parent rate node?

Answer (score 0):

If your xml looks like this:

```
<rates>
  <rate>
    <loantype>40-Year Fixed Rate</loantype>
    <subtype>A</subtype>
    <rate> 5.500</rate>
    <points> 0.500</points>
    <apr> 5.579</apr>
    <jumbo>0</jumbo>
    <fixed>1</fixed>
  </rate>
  <rate>
    <loantype>10-Year Floating Rate</loantype>
    <subtype>B</subtype>
    <rate> 3.500</rate>
    <points> 0.500</points>
    <apr> 5.579</apr>
    <jumbo>0</jumbo>
    <fixed>1</fixed>
      </rate>
  </rates>
```

this xpath expression

```
//rate[loantype="40-Year Fixed Rate"][subtype="A"]/rate
```

should select

```
5.500
```

Comment: Thank  you but I wanted to use ancestor, parent or descendant

Comment: @kt123 Not sure what you mean; this uses one ancestor and 3 sibling children.

Comment: you can implement xPath using word ancestor